# How to add ports in gogole cloud virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

How to add ports in google cloud virtual machine, I want to add some ports to the virtual machine I created in google cloud, should i add port separately to each VM instance created

Comment: You don't add ports to Virtual Machines. You bind processes on the VM to its ports and then you program the firewall to allow (or deny) other hosts access to the ports. See [VPC firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) for more details on Compute Engine's distributed firewall service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create firewall rules.

In the GCP menu: VPC Network -> Firewall -> CREATE FIREWALL RULE (button).

In the destination configuration, you need to insert the tags of your instance so it will be possible to have a rule for each instance.

Follow Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls